# WPF Custom Control Dependency Property setter not getting called?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have created a custom control CustomTextBox inherited from TextBox class. I have created a dependency property named CustomTextProperty.

I have binded this DP with my Viewmodel property.

While Registering the DP i have given the property change callback but it is only get called one time when my control gets the binded data initially when my xaml loads.

When i try to set my control from view the binded VM property setter does not gets called and also the propertychangecallback not gets fired.

Please help!!

Code snipet below:

My Custom control

```
class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CustomText",
                                                               typeof(string), typeof(CustomTextBox),
                                                               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("CustomTextBox",
                                                               FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                               new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCustomPropertyChange)));

 public string CustomText
 {
   get { return (string)GetValue(CustomTextProperty); }
   set { SetValue(CustomTextProperty, value); }
 }

 private static void OnCustomPropertyChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
   // This is Demo Application.
   // Code to be done Later...
 }
}
```

My View Model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private string textForTextBox;

 public string TextForCustomTextBox
 {
   get
   {
     return this.textForTextBox;
   }
   set
   {
     this.textForTextBox = value;

     this.OnPropertyChange("TextForCustomTextBox");
   }
 }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 public void OnPropertyChange(string name)
 {
   PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

   if (handler != null)
   {
     handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
   }
 }
}
```

My Xaml Code with Binding:

```
<custom:CustomTextBox x:Name="CustomTextBox" 
                                  CustomText="{Binding TextForCustomTextBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="50" />
```

My Code Behind to set DataContext:

```
// My View Constructor
public View1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Post code that how are you setting it from code behind?

Comment: Where's the code that sets the `DataContext`?  Did you set a `DataContext` somewhere in the XAML or in the code-behind?  Everything you've posted looks like it will work.

Comment: Thanks for replying... i have edited the code above showing datacontext to be set to my ViewModel class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you declared a `CustomText DependencyProperty` and data bound it to your view model `TextForCustomTextBox` property and that much is correct. However, when you said that you tried to set your property from the view, you were mistaken.

What you were *actually* doing was setting the `CustomTextBox .Text` property from the view and that wasn't connected to your `CustomTextBox.CustomText` property. You can connect them like this, although I'm not quite sure what the point of that would be:

```
<Views:CustomTextBox x:Name="CustomTextBox" Text="{Binding CustomText, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource Self}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CustomText="{Binding 
    TextForCustomTextBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="50" />
```

Comment: Thanks Sheridan... your provided solution made it work. Actually there is no point of doing so, but i m learning WPF and want to learn every in and out of this technology. Can you suggest me any good documentation or handbook for learning WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your DataContext BEFORE the actual initialization so it is available when the form/control objects are created.  If it can't find before, is that what may be causing the failed bindings.